# PHP Mysql radio buttons selection

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me please, I am trying to implement a simple php MySQL survey, but I am stuck on this, how do I store the specific selection in MySQL that users select.

How satisfied are you:

```
<table id="table1" rules="all" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="70%">
    <colgroup width="70%"></colgroup>
    <colgroup width="6%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
           <th></th>
           <th font="" style="font-size:9pt;" size="2"><b>Dissatisfied</b></th>
           <th font="" style="font-size:9pt;" size="2"><b>Satisfied</b></th>
           <th font="" style="font-size:9pt;" size="2"><b>Very Satisfied</b></th> 
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr align="center">
           <td align="left"><font style="font-size:10pt;"><b>Technician's ability to understand the unique nature of your problem?</b></font></td>
           <td><input name="satisfaction" value="Dissatisfied"  type="radio"></td>
           <td><input name="satisfaction" value="Satisfied"  type="radio"></td>
           <td><input name="satisfaction" value="Very Satisfied"  type="radio"></td>

       </tr>
       <tr align="center">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Long time ago since I've last seen `<font>` tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this what you need will need **a form** to submit data selection. You will need **two php files**

The first one is to built **a form of radio buttons**. I had removed table's elements for neat view then we set the URL of the second page .Can also be a single page if you want but this is more easier.

feedback.php

```
 <form action="add.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
     <input name="satisfaction" value="Dissatisfied"  type="radio">Dissatisfied<br>
     <input name="satisfaction" value="Satisfied"  type="radio">Satisfied<br>
     <input name="satisfaction" value="Very Satisfied"  type="radio">Very Satisfied<br>

     <input type='submit' value="submit">
</form>
```

In the second page **we catch what we had posted from first page**.

add.php

```
  $result= $_POST['satisfaction'];
  echo $result;
```

using $result to store in your database. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

As simple as :

1st, Add this line before the table tag:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

2nd, this one at the end of your code:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you can have this code for inserting in the DB.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLENAME(COLUMN NAME) values (?)")) {
     $stmt->bind_param('s', $satisfaction);


    $satisfaction=$_POST['satisfaction'];

     $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a billion Wayne Tun Myint, auicsc for the quick reply, Wayne

Comment: Thank you a billion Wayne Tun Myint, auicsc for the quick reply, Wayne was quick and easy, i really appreciate your help, i wish one day i help others as you do, Ozkan Ozlu i have been banging my head over this tried almost everyting maybe i missed some minor detail. All the best.

Comment: Hi auicsc is there an option where to accept your and Wayne answer ? because both of the solutions helped me.

Comment: @user2303233, no there is not. You can accept the one that helped you most :)

Comment: i accepted Wayne solution as it is the one i used. Much appreciated for your help though.

Comment: @-user2303233 and @-auicsc glad to help and nice meeting you all. :)

Comment: @auicsc Can not upvote i need 15 reputations, Nice meeting you too Wayne and thanks again.